# what is new default keyboard shortcut for 'fold all' in vscode(visual studio code ) version 1.2.0?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

in VSCode 1.1.0 the key combination "ctrl+shift+alt+["  was for "Fold all".but it doesn`t work for newly released 1.2.0 version. what is new keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I just found : 
ctl+k ctl+0   
or
ctl+k 0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has moved to Ctrl+K Ctrl+0 which I found from at the following page [Code Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings)